# get sim country ISO from multiple sim devices and e-sim devices

Tags: android, telephony, country-codes

in regular cases where the user have a physical sim is his device i would get the country culture code by the following code:

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) cxt.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    //getNetworkCountryIso
    if (manager != null && manager.getSimCountryIso() != null) {
        return manager.getSimCountryIso().toLowerCase();
    }
```

but when having 2 sims in the device what will happen to the above code? and how would i get the country ISO code when the device is holding an e-sim rather then a physical sim.

Answer (score 0):

Your code gets Country ISO of SIM which is at slot which at 1, which will not care about other SIM slots.

In order to read all sim slots, get SIM subscriprtion's by calling [SubscriptionManager.getSubscriptionId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager#getSubscriptionIds(int)) which will return an array of `subscription ID's`
As we know Android Multiple SIM support is totally based on manufacturers, in Google android, in case dual/multi-SIM, you can update your `TelephonyManager` something like below :

```
subIds[] = SubscriptionManager.getSubscriptionIds(slotInex) //Pass slot index ex: 0,1 etc

for(int i=0;i<subIds.lenth();i++){

 if (SubscriptionManager.isActiveSubscriptionId(subIds[i])){
       TelephonyManager manager = telephonyManager.createForSubscriptionId(subIds[i]);
        if (manager != null && manager.getSimCountryIso() != null) {
           System.out.println(manager.getSimCountryIso().toLowerCase());
      }
    }
}
```